# VC++ 6.0 App must run as Admin to access a DB in the Common Application Data area

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an old C++/MFC app written with VS 6.  I am trying to make it compliant with Windows Vista and 7 by moving the DB directory to the Common Application Data area.  But when I try to open the Access DB using DAO it reads the primary table, finds no records, and reports that no data is found.  However, if I select "Run as Admin", then I can access it without an issue.

Should I be storing the database in another location?  If not, why does it fail to read the table correctly?

Also, I have tried using the manifest listed below, that I found online, but it does not seem to force the application to run as admin and so I still get the no data found message.  But I don't know much about manifests yet, so it could be that I didn't configure it correctly.

Thanks for any help or advise you can give.

FieldAppl

Comment: philgyro: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm trapped with a *pre*-MFC VS6 project :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the manifest I used to ensure my custom-written installer ran as an administrator. In addition to this manifest, I also digitally signed the application with a Verisign certificate.

Scott

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="Setup"
     type="win32"/> 

  <description>Software Installation</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly
```

>